# How to send HTML text to Model in Spring MVC

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc

I have webmvc application with jsp-page as a view.

Here one of my mapping methods:

```
@RequestMapping("vacancy/{id}")
public String showVacancy(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {

    Vacancy vacancy = vacancyRepository.findOne(new ObjectId(id));
    model.addAttribute("description", vacancy.getDescription());

    return "vacancy";

}
```

Here the part of vacancy.jsp:

```
<body>

<h1><c:out value="${title}"/></h1>
<hr>

<h2>Description</h2>
<c:out value="${description}"/>

</body>
```

As you can see, I trying to send description to jsp-attribute `${description}`.
The problem here is in that description. It has html-tags. For example

`<p><strong>Responsibilities:</strong></p>`

And after rendering I get quite strange html page that includes that description with all tags :(

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you please add response page?

Comment: Response page is the same as description = "<p><strong>Responsibilities:</strong></p>" (that tags don`t render to html-view, just plain text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass html the same way you pass text. You just need the jtsl code to not escape the html by using the escapeXml="false" directive.

For example:

```
<c:out value="${fn:replace(row.entryText, newLineChar, '<br>')}" escapeXml="false" />
```