# How to assign html block to a model and send it to front-end in Spring

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, model

Hei there.

I wonder if it's possible to assign a whole  container with some html stuff to a model and pass to front-end like it works with bean objects?

I need it for a little survey program when admin user can change/add more questions to the survey.

I know it sounds weird and it can be easily done on fron-end, but i just wonder if it is even possible?

Thanks

Comment: see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808110/how-to-send-html-text-to-model-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yes it can be done by just assigning the html code(tags) to string and then the string to model, it is tested and it work, but i see no usage for it anymore